# Why to use .then() rather than async/await inside loop that returns promise?

Tags: javascript, loops, async-await, promise, es6-promise

I came across multiple articles about the topic how to properly push new promises from a loop that does multiple API calls inside the new promise into an array.
The code inside the returned promise should run consecutively and after the loop the code should only continue when ALL promises inside the array are resolved (therefore I use `Promise.all()`).

The version that would be intuitive for me:

```js
const returnPromisesAsyncAwait = async () => {
  let pArray = []

  for (let i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    pArray.push(
      // Is this antipattern?
      new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        console.log('Entered promise' + i)
        await new Promise((res) => setTimeout(res, i * 100))
        console.log('Finished promise 1 inside promise' + i)
        await new Promise((res) => setTimeout(res, i * 500))
        console.log('Finished promise 2 inside promise' + i)
        resolve(true)
      })
    )
  }

  await Promise.all(pArray)
  console.log(pArray)
  console.log('Done!')
}

returnPromisesAsyncAwait()
```

This code returns exactly the same output than the second one which should be pattern correct:

```js
const returnPromisesThen = async () => {
  let pArray = []

  for (let i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    pArray.push(
      // Is this antipattern?
      new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        console.log('Entered promise' + i)
        new Promise((res) => setTimeout(res, i * 100)).then(() => {
          console.log('Finished promise 1 inside promise ' + i)
          new Promise((res) => setTimeout(res, i * 500)).then(() => {
            console.log('Finished promise 2 inside promise ' + i)
            resolve(true)
          })
        })
      })
    )
  }

  await Promise.all(pArray)
  console.log(pArray)
  console.log('Done!')
}

returnPromisesThen()
```

Are there any reasons why one should rather use the .then() syntax than the async/await one in this case?

Comment: what would you rather read?

Comment: How old were the articles? there's a lot of articles on the internet from before async/await existed, however, just because async/await exists doesn't mean the previous ways of accomplishing it are invalid.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, both code will result in the same behavior. So it is fine to use async/await.

The risk within loop is top-level await;  e.g

```js
for (let i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    await fetch();
}
```

Doing this would pause the loop until each promise resolved. This would cause performance issue since all promises would resolve in a serial way. This is usually a bad pattern since it defeat the purpose of asynchronous calls.

If you only use async/await in your promise callbacks, then it's fine.

Another similar common issue is awaiting multiple calls next to each other vs using `Promise.all()`:

```
- const a = await fetchA();
- const b = await fetchB(); // Here fetchB doesn't start until fetchA complete.

+ const [a, b] = Promise.all([
+     fetchA(),
+     fetchB(),
+ ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the "issue" by putting the code inside the loop into an external async function so I don't run into the problem adding an async function to a new promise.

```js
asyncProcess = async (i) => {
  console.log('Entered promise' + i)
  await new Promise((res) => setTimeout(res, i * 100))
  console.log('Finished promise 1 inside promise' + i)
  await new Promise((res) => setTimeout(res, i * 500))
  console.log('Finished promise 2 inside promise' + i)
}

const returnPromiseWithExternalProcess = async () => {
  let pArray = []

  for (let i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    pArray.push(asyncProcess(i))
  }

  await Promise.all(pArray)
  console.log(pArray)
  console.log('Done!')
}

returnPromiseWithExternalProcess()
```